# CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey error when gitk

Tags: css, xcode, git, version-control, terminal

can someone explain ho to resolve this error:

**CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed this URL which has no scheme:**

it´s probably caused by xCode when i try to gitk or gitk --all in the Terminal. It started to appear after the Mountain Lion upgrade.  Thanks :)

Error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785126/cfurlcopyresourcepropertyforkey-failed-because-it-was-passed-this-url-which-has) which recommends [this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11896752/877115)

Answer (score 2):

I got this error just now and find a solution to solve it.

I was trying to invoke the function getResourceValue:forKey:error: in my project and my os version is 10.7.5.

I init a new NSURL object by using + URLWithString: and the problem occurred before, after I replace it with + fileURLWithPath:, it's ok now.

The difference value between the two objects with different functions is /Volumes/Data/a file://localhost/Volumes/Data/a/

Apple has statemented that about NSURL class below,

Handling Object Creation Failure The NSURL class fails to create a new NSURL object if the path being passed is not well-formed; the path must comply with RFC 2396. Examples of cases that will not succeed are strings containing space characters and high-bit characters. Should creating an NSURL object fail, the creation methods return nil, which you must be prepared to handle. If you are creating NSURL objects using file system paths, you should use fileURLWithPath: or initFileURLWithPath:, which handle the subtle differences between URL paths and file system paths. If you wish to be tolerant of malformed path strings, you’ll need to use functions provided by the Core Foundation framework to clean up the strings.

Error while using getResourceValue:forKey method in NSURL

Answer (score 1):

On Mountain Lion 10.8.2, I fixed this issue when calling gitk from terminal by installing/upgrading tcl and tk.

brew install tcl
brew install tk

The UI of gitk will likely change, but you can tweak that in ~/.gitk.

Comment: It also changes hotkeys, and cmd-tab functionality, keyboard repeat speed (which can be fixed). I ended up reverting =\